# Cast an object to Decimal? or Int? etc but leave it as null if it is null

Tags: c#, converting, null, casting

In a case like this:

```
object A1 = null;
Decimal? B = Convert.ToDecimal(A1);
object A2 = null;
int? C = Convert.ToInt32(A2);
```

Note that in case where `A1` or `A2` have values, they appear to be of type `double`.

`B` and `C` will be `0` instead of `null`. `A1` actually comes from Excel via the interop and `(Decimal?)A1` throws an error: *Specified cast is not valid.* yet `Convert.ToDecimal(A1)` works. The problem is that if `A1` is `null`, I want `B` to also be `null`

So at the moment I'm solving it like this:

```
Func<object, Decimal?> convertOrNullDecimal = x => x == null ? (Decimal?)null : Convert.ToDecimal(x);
Func<object, int?> convertOrNullInt32 = x => x == null ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(x);

B = convertOrNullDecimal(A1);
C = convertOrNullDecimal(A2);
```

Is this a reasonable way to go? Or can I refactor that into a single function? It's possible I'll have to add other numeric data types later on...

I tried it like this:

```
public static Decimal? convertOrNull(object x)
{
    return x == null ? (Decimal?)null : Convert.ToDecimal(x);
}
public static int? convertOrNull(object x)
{
    return x == null ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(x);
}
```

but then the calls become ambiguous. I guess you can't overload based on output variable type...

Also note that if I try `B = A1 as Decimal?`, then if `A1` had a numerical value, `B` is still `null` because it looks like Excel passed numeric cells as doubles and empty cells as `null`

Comment: okay... what's your question? I don't understand where you're going... This reads more like a "I have problem x and I want it solved." and not like "I have solved problem x, is this solution good?"

Comment: @Vogel612 it is solved - it works. My question is is there a better way to solve it than making a function (like mine above) for each input type?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know that the `object` is always either `double` or `null`, then that's exactly what the `double?` type can represent and you can convert to that using a cast:

```
object obj = ...;
double? doubleValue = (double?)obj;
```

And once you have `double?`, you can cast it to `decimal?` and it will work both for the case when the value is `null` and when isn't:

```
decimal? decimalValue = (decimal?)doubleValue;
```

Or, on a single line:

```
decimal? decimalValue = (decimal?)(double?)obj;
```

Apart from being clear, this approach is also likely going to be pretty efficient.

Answer (score 9):

Use generics that's all:

```
    public static T? ConvertTo<T>(object x) where T : struct
    {
        return x == null ? null : (T?)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you are worried about doubles coming through instead of Decimals but you could just assign with a ternary like this

```
var B = A1 == null ? null : A1;
```

This way `B` will be the same type as `A1`

Most of the time a Method or Function that takes a Decimal value should also take a Double value,  Doubles are smaller than Decimals

Single, Double, Decimal are kind of like Integer types

- Single = 4 bytes (*short = 2 bytes*)
- Double = 8 Bytes (*int = 4 bytes*)
- Decimal = 12 bytes (*long = 8 bytes*)

([Decimal vs. Double](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/decimal-vs-double-difference?forum=csharpgeneral))

---

***Note:*** Assuming that **decimal values are necessary**

You could just do the conversion after you assign to the variable (after checking for null).

You might be able to assign straight across actually

```
decimal B = A1 == null ? null : A1;
```

but you need a nullable decimal (`decimal?`) *Another Assumption*

Instead of assigning null to the Decimal you have to assign it's default value using `default(decimal?)` which I assume comes out as null.

```
decimal? B = A1 == null ? default(decimal?) : Convert.ToDecimal(A1);
```

Google and MSDN are awesome resources to figure stuff like this out.

(as well as [StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308524/1214743))

---

playing around with this if you don't want a nullable Decimal you can also write it like this

```
decimal C = A1 == null ? default(decimal) : Convert.ToDecimal(A1);
```

Comment: Yes, `default(decimal?)` is the same as `null`. And instead of `default(decimal)`, you can write just `0m`.